# xml_parse huge file PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a issue with PHP function xml_parse. It's not working with huge files - I have xml file with 10MB size.

Problem is, that I have old XML-RPC library from Zend and there are another functions (element handlers and case folding).

```
$parser_resource = xml_parser_create('utf-8');

xml_parser_set_option($parser_resource, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, true);
xml_set_element_handler($parser_resource, 'XML_RPC_se', 'XML_RPC_ee');
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser_resource, 'XML_RPC_cd');
if (!xml_parse($parser_resource, $data, 1)) {
    // ends here with 10MB file    
}
```

On another place, I just use siple_load_xml_file with option LIBXML_PARSEHUGE, but in this case I don't know what can I do.

Best way will be, if function xml_parse will have some parameter for huge files too.

Thank you for your advices

Error is:
XML error: No memory at line ...

Comment: Did you had a look at the memory consumption while running the command ? Did you run out of ram maybe ?

Comment: I'll try ini_set with 256MB, but error still occured. I see that there is one element with 8MB - if it means something.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk length of file to parse could be to huge.

if you use fread

```
while ($data = fread($fp, 1024*1024)) {...}
```

use smaller length (at my case it has to be smaller than 10 MB) e.g. 1MB and put the xml_parse function in the while loop.